# How can scroll screen to clicked div in mobile view

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery

Open link in mobile or in >600px device : http://dev.mpex.com/ee14/team-2018
Click on any team image. after open description cursor goes to top. we need to keep on clicked image. when I click to this image focus needs on this.

```
if(jQuery(window).width()<=600){
     jQuery(".tc1").on("click",function(){ 
        jQuery('.main-block-added').hide();
        jQuery(this).find('.main-block-added').toggle();
        jQuery(this).find('.member-name').toggle();
        jQuery(this).find('.member-post').toggle();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you the exact code by reading your requirement but you can try something like below to scroll at clicked div:

```
if(jQuery(window).width()<=600){
  $(".tc1").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".tc1").offset().top
    }, 2000);
  });
}
```